# Insert an array structure in the string in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs

How do I insert into the database the array structure of objects as a string?

```
$scope.lists = [
    {
        label: "Parcerias Principais",
        allowedTypes: ['p1'],
        class: "b1",
        people: []
    },
    {
        label: "Atividades Principais",
        allowedTypes: ['p2'],
        class: "b2",
        people: []
    }
];


$scope.salvar = function(){ 
    $http.post('link', { 
        aluno: 1, 
        tarefa: $scope.lists, 
        data: new Date(), 
        dataultima: new Date(), 
        curso: 82}).then(function(resultado){ 
            $ret = resultado.data; 
            console.log($ret); 
    }); 
}
```

expected outcome:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KErXa.png)

I want to insert my direct array into the SQLSERVER database in this way.

Comment: where is your php and ajax call?

Comment: I put the $http call in question

Comment: @AdrielOliveira and the php?

Comment: I just want to send the entire array as a string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try JSON.stringify as used below :

```
$scope.salvar = function(){ 
    $http.post('link', { 
        aluno: 1, 
        tarefa: JSON.stringify($scope.lists), 
        data: new Date(), 
        dataultima: new Date(), 
        curso: 82}).then(function(resultado){ 
            $ret = resultado.data; 
            console.log($ret); 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: welcome, @AdrielOliveira. I have voted your question +1 up. now it is not -1 :)